# High bandwith/ low latency wireless sensor network

Tags: wireless, bandwidth

I have a field of anywhere from 16 to 32 sensors that have to all transmit around 2Mbps simultaneously and continuously (I could possibly bring this down to around 1Mbps if it is the only way). The field has a diameter of around 100 ft. Also, I need a maximum of about 5ms latency but no error correction needed(but it must be kept to a minimum and interference is an issue). It is analog data and the sensors are self contained entities(no master controller). A bit here and there being out of place is not a problem.

I've been reading a little bit a little about ANT, Zigbee, Bluetooth low energy, etc and I'm not sure if it is possible to use these devices.

24*2Mbps = 48Mbps so the theoretical bandwidth would be about 50MHz... WiFi has a 16 channels with a bandwidth of about 22MHz each and a total bandwidth about 350MHz.

So it seems completely reasonable to be able to do this but I would like to use something that is efficient, safe, and proven. Wi-Fi would be relatively good except it has too few channels. Ant seems to have a lot of nice interference prevention mechanisms but I have no idea if it supports the number of channels, bandwidth, and latency I need.

It would be disastrous (not life and death but a loss of necessary data) if someone walked in the field with a mobile device and interfered with a sensor unless it was accidental... and it may be the case there will be several cell phones or wireless devices.

Comment: You have quite strong requirements about data rate, latency, range and reliability; I'm not sure they can be met.

Comment: @Uiy - If your sensors are for measuring explosions (seismic?) I don't see the need to have continuous data. I'd rather think of bursts, which don't even have to be real-time if you can add timestamps to the data (like from a GPS receiver). Just trying to ease your requirements.

Comment: Another option you might want to consider is to compress your data. There is no need for it to be anything extreme. For example, you might be able to save bandwidth by only transmitting when your data actually changes. I find it hard to believe that 2Mbps is constantly new data with no duplication. You could also only transmit the part of the data that is changing, like if you have an 16 bit value, but only 8 of the bits ever change. The other 8 bits could be sent from time to time and whenever they might change.

Comment: @Uiy - If we're trying to change the question it is to take the problem up one level. You need to collect a lot of data and see the wireless mesh as the solution. We're seeing a lot of problems given your requirements, so it's a natural engineer's reaction to question the requirements. You compare with scopes and audio, but don't say anything to justify the requirements for your own sensor network. Kellen suggests compression, and I wonder if the data is really continuous. It would help if you told us more about your application.

Comment: @Uiy - people are trying to help you, first by trying to understand what you really need. But your unrefined reactions are nothing like stackexchange. I suggest you read some other questions and their answers to learn how people behave here. Meanwhile I vote to close the question.

Comment: @Uiy, stevenvh, Kellenjb, and clabacchio - Please do not get into comment wars.

Comment: For who doesn't understand what some comments refer to: a few dozen comments were deleted.

Comment: I am not positive, but you might want to look into the regulations for the band. I could see restrictions in places that prevent you from using all of the channels for a system.

Comment: I think that [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) has something to do with the discussion that came out, even if not completely related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need it to be a mesh? I'm thinking that would be a requirement for two reasons:

- You need that a sensor be able to also receive data from other sensors, because it would do some processing on it
- The receiver is not in the range of all sensors, so some of them would retransmit data received by the others

In the first case I'd need more info about what you need to do to offer alternatives, but the second could be avoided just increasing the range (which, for the number of sensors you mentioned, wouldn't be a problem if they are not far apart).

Anyway, if you could use another configuration, there's the [Nordic line of 2.4 GHz transceivers](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF) which are able to transmit data at 2 Mbps, and have 125 channels. The problem is that the receiver would need either as many transceivers as there are sensors, or fewer transceivers switching channels (which would reduce the effective bandwidth). But anyway the only alternative you would have to this is WiFi. BT, ANT, Zigbee were not designed to support much high bandwidths. Maybe you could use BT but you'd have the same restrictions as with the 2.4 GHz transceivers, and BT chipsets are more expensive. That's a problem with WiFi, too. Also WiFi tends to consume more power.

Sparkfun has a nice [breakout](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/152) for a Nordic transceiver. It's for an older model that goes up to 1Mbps, but it's a quick way to try a prototype.

Comment: No, not really a mesh. The sensors just broadcast. I shouldn't have used the word mesh as that implies bi-dir comm I suppose. Why I used it because I wanted to try to leverage existing mesh technologies(ANT, zigbee, etc...) if possible.  Those audio txrx are very close to what I need. 20ms is too high though. 125 channels at 2Mpbs is very good. I'd rather have 1/3 of the channels and 3x the bandwidth though ;) If the latency could be reduced a bit then these devices would work.

Comment: With compression I might be able to reduce the data more. If I go with lossy compression I could definitely get the data rates down but I'm not sure how this would effect the data analysis.  This is not to say that I wouldn't mind bi-dir comm. The rx could be at a much lower rate... for example, could use it for sensor heath status, control information, etc...

Comment: These devices may be very close to what I can use. I do not like the 20ms latency but I can reduce the bandwidth slightly and if these numbers of 2Mbps are the throughput then it should work excluding the latency. What it does due is show that it is possible. I might have to roll my own txrx but I could follow a similar structure. I'm not sure how these devices work in the real world but if I do end up rolling my own I can reduce the # of channels and increase the bandwidth and implement a sort of burst mode(since I have 5ms to play with).

Comment: Well, they are pretty easy to setup, especially if you use the breakout board. Basically you set the parameters (bandwidth, channel, etc.) and a flag to say if it's in tx or rx mode. I've always used them as a pair, but AFAIK they would work in broadcast mode as well. You don't need to worry about transport protocol, they have it built-in, so once it's up you just start to read/write data through SPI. I had a prototype working for a point-to-point device with a pair of breakout boards in about one afternoon.

Comment: About the latency, I don't think there's much that can be done about it, but you'd probably face similar or worse times with the other protocols, they are somewhat more complex.

Comment: Yeah, but 20ms latency is probably too much for my application(it is right at the boundary).  What this does though is give me reasonable expectations that what I'm trying to do can be done. If they've made these devices to do something very close to what I want then I could potentially create a similar device tailored to my specific needs. But to get a prototype done I could use these devices as a start instead of investing all the time and money to develop such a device.

Comment: The biggest problem I have is not the RF stuff as it's quite simple to create a wireless transmission circuit(as you can get ic's nowdays that contain virtually all the circuitry). The issue is with interference and fcc regulation... which is why I do not want to roll my own.  I do not know enough about the issues to know how feasible it is to do what I want but the product you have mention suggests that it is highly doable. I'm still a big worried about cells, wireless computing, and such will effect my application.

Comment: I'm thinking that I could use a burst transmission instead. I could buffer about 5ms of data and transmit it in a package based format with ERC's and if I have high enough throughout put I might even be able to resend data if necessary. Anyways, It is something to workout and I am at least more confident that it can be done somewhat easy... and maybe I can get a prototype up and running much quicker with the devices you have suggested. (I might go with those audio ones as they are very close to what I need... maybe 20ms latency to start and go from there).

Comment: With such transceivers you'll probably not have problems of cellphone interference, but keep in mind that the 2.4 GHz band is widely used for consumer devices like cordless phones, garage door remotes, etc. So if your sensors are near such devices, they'll "compete" for available channels.

Comment: @fceonel: yes, that is what I am worried about. If I had my own dedicated chunk of bandwidth I would have no problems. It's designing a system that can handle play along with all the other devices that use such a small chunk and still stay within spec. It's just something I'm going to have to look more into but at least I can get a prototype up and running quickly with pre-made devices and expect it to work reasonably well.